# Does it make a difference if you don't use a prop in your PureComponent render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

Say I have a PureComponent with a bunch of props. If I don't use every single prop in my render method, will it affect anything at all?

For instance, if I depend on `componentWillReceiveProps` being called for every single prop, even the ones that are not rendered...it will still be called, correct?

I can't imagine the React authors doing anything else... I can probably hunt down the code and take a peek myself and I will if I can't get a definitive answer here. Thanks.

NOTE: The reason I'm asking is because I'm wondering I see some code that is pulling unused variables from props [here](https://github.com/nkbt/react-debounce-input/blob/master/src/Component.js#L177).

Comment: So, every prop key is being copied [here](https://github.com/nkbt/react-debounce-input/blob/master/src/Component.js#L185) anyway, so I don't see what the possible point could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PureComponent` is just like a regular component, only it implements the lifecycle method `shouldComponentUpdate()`. This function will ultimately determine if `render()` will run, so it cannot possibly rely on `render()` itself.

> For instance, if I depend on componentWillReceiveProps being called for every single prop, even the ones that are not rendered...it will still be called, correct?

Yes, that is correct.

---

The code you referenced contains a common pattern, where `props` should be passed down, but not as a whole. The omitted props are commonly known as `ownProps`, which indicates that they belong solely to the component itself.

If we look at the code:

```
const {
    element,
    onChange: _onChange,
    value: _value,
    minLength: _minLength,
    //...
    ...props
 } = this.props;
```

In this case, `value`, `minLength` and `debounceTimeout` are only assigned to variables so they will be excluded from the `props` variable, which is used [afterwards](https://github.com/nkbt/react-debounce-input/blob/7ce125e9b3cf93f0d18899949c895f41046cb9c5/src/Component.js#L209).

```
return React.createElement(element, {
    ...props,
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just figured this out as I tried to remove the unused vars and tested the result!

Answer (score 1):

> For instance, if I depend on componentWillReceiveProps being called for every single prop, even the ones that are not rendered...it will still be called, correct?

Yes `componentWillReceiveProps` will still be called regardless of what effect a particular prop may or may not have on rendering.

> *even the ones that are not rendered*

Note many props are not rendered themselves, but they may have some effect on rendering (or they may not). React would not know if a particular prop affected rendering at least until the new virtual DOM was constructed.